# mysql_fetch_array issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, web

Here is the code:

```
<select name="op1" id="op1" class="op1">
    <option value=""> -- please choose -- </option>
    <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
<br />
<select name="op2" id="op2" style="margin-top:20px" class="op2">
    <option value=""> -- please choose -- </option>
    <?php
        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cat2 WHERE cor = '$id' ORDER BY id ASC");
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
            $id2 = $row2['id'];
            $name2 = $row2['name'];
            echo '<option value="'.$id2.'">'.$name2.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

What I want to do is select $id from the first loop and use it in the second loops query but cant seem to get it to work because of the variable pipeline, does anyone know a work around for this?

Comment: That requires submitting the form, right?

Comment: Do you mean use the user's chosen value from the first SELECT when populating values in the second SELECT?

Comment: Which `$id` from the first loop do you want to use in the second query? PHP runs on the server BEFORE sending the page to the browser, so it can't depend on what the user selects. For that, you need to use AJAX.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I was wondering too! Looking at the OP's comment on Alqin's answer below, that's exactly what they were trying to do.

Comment: An alternative to AJAX is to populate the second `<select>` with hidden groups of `<option>` tags, and use Javascript to show the ones appropriate for the one chosen in the first `<select>`.

Comment: I am using jQuery to slide down the second Select Box, When the user picks the first option in the First select box i want it to slide down the second box (Already have that working) But i need help getting the data from the mysql database into that second select box based on the users first choice.

Comment: What does your jQuery-code look like right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
 $ids=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $id = $row['id'];
        $ids[]=$id;
        $name = $row['name'];
        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }
?>
```

second php block;

```
<?php
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cat2 WHERE cor = '$id' ORDER BY id ASC");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
        $id2 = $row2['id'];
        $name2 = $row2['name'];
        echo '<option value="'.$id2.'">'.$name2.'</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

The next line of codes are using ajax. You have to create a new file called ajax.php. You can use the same file, put all the code from ajax.php (adding the exit; at the end) at the very top of the document and  change ...load('ajax.php'... with ...load(''...

If you place the script in the head of the doc you will have to wrap it in $(function(){}); to run after all the element in the page are loaded.

Not tested code. But here we go. If I'm wrong somewhere, please anyone comment.

**AJAX**

```
    <select name="op1" id="op1" class="op1">
        <option value=""> -- please choose -- </option>
        <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $name = $row['name'];
                echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select name="op2" id="op2" style="margin-top:20px;" class="op2">

    </select>

 <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#op1').change(function() {
          $('#op2').load('ajax.php',{id:$(this).val()});
     });

 </script>
```

ajax.php file:

```
   <?php if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {  $id = $_REQUEST['id']; ?>
      <option value=""> -- please choose -- </option>
        <?php
            $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cat2 WHERE cor = '$id' ORDER BY id ASC");
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
                $id2 = $row2['id'];
                $name2 = $row2['name'];
                echo '<option value="'.$id2.'">'.$name2.'</option>';
            }
        } ?>
```

Comment: That just makes id the value of 1 no matter what the user selects

Comment: @mtcamesao If you're trying to populate the second SELECT with what the user has selected from the first one, you can't do it like this, as the whole HTML (including the PHP-generated HTML) is output at once. You'll need to submit the user's SELECT choice either via AJAX or using a FORM submit, before generating the second SELECT.

Comment: I edited my answer, I'll come back letter with an ajax example.

Comment: Add it ajax example. Not tested, but should point in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to want to load the second tables, just keeps saing --please choose--

Comment: Debug the code. See what you have in each line. On javascript before load something like var id =$(this).val(); console.log(id);$('#op2').load('ajax.php',{id:$(this).val(id)}); see what you get in ajax file, then go to database and see if you select the right thing.

Comment: I got it working :] I had to include the connection :P Thanks again!

Comment: I forgot to mention to connect again to database in ajax file. If this helped, make it accepted answer and you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> When the user picks the first option in the First select box i want it to slide down the second box (Already have that working) But i need help getting the data from the mysql database into that second select box based on the users first choice.

For what you want you'll need to:

- Gather the selected first option by jQuery (client side)
- Perform an AJAX request via [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or synonyms (client side)
- Define the landing page for the AJAX request to gather the informations (server side)
- Update the second option set (client side)